# Android Studio not recognizing any symbols, variables, imports etc

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I'm facing an issue with my Android Studio. If you look at the attachment below everything is unrecognized. Everything is in red. Autocomplete for coding is not working however, my code is 100% correct and the application works great on the mobile device.

It is so annoying... I have reinstalled Android Studio several times (fresh install) and still not working.

I don't know how to fix it. If anyone faced this issue before please let me know how you fixed it. Help a brother out am about to lose it.

[image: Android-Studio]

Comment: update your sdk manager once

Comment: please share your build.gradle also

Comment: Its not just for this app. Its the same issue on all my projects. @Bunny

Comment: @sasikumar I did. Didn't help anything. any other ideas? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try these two options once, This might work for you

1. You can resolved it by clicking **File > Invalidate Caches /
   Restart... > Invalidate and Restart.** When Android Studio restarted
   and indexed all code again.
2. You can also try resolving it by going to
   **File > Sync with File System** and then closing the project and
   importing it again

You may need to resync with the gradle again but hopefully it works for you

Comment: Thank you for the support. but I tried both options but non worked for me. I'm so close to punch Android Studio in the face lol

Comment: Which is the OS you are using?

Comment: Windows 10. I tried my project on another PC and it worked fine. But every project I import on my PC or Create on Android Studio same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your SDK and JDK locations are set properly?

Have a look at **File -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> Android SDK Location / JDK Location**

Comment: Yes because the app actually compiles and its been uploaded to the store too